# Java version 1.6 UnsatisfiedLinkError on load shared library, Java 1.4 works fine?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Problem solved. libjnidiagnosticsserver.so was missing linker lib and path to libfesdiagnosticsserver.so. Java 1.4 must be more liberal on locating undefined symbols than Java 1.6. Thank you all for your help. Any suggestions on etiquette for closing this equitably?

( Disclaimer: Java newbie )

I wrote a Java application that uses JNI to call my C++ shared library.  It prints java version and gets and prints LD_LIBRARY_PATH when executed.

Java version 1.4 - All is good!:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar "javadiagnosticsserver-test.jar"
java version=1.4.2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/lib/fesdiagnostics
```

Java version 1.6 - **UnsatisfiedLinkError**:

The "***undefined symbol***" **_ZN17DiagnosticsServerC1Ev** is defined in **libfesdiagnosticsserver.so**.  Java 1.4 sees it, Java 1.6 does not?  The System.loadLibrary("fesdiagnosticsserver") call works. Java 1.6 loadLibrary does not know where to look?

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/java -jar "javadiagnosticsserver-test.jar"
version=1.6.0_26
class path=javadiagnosticsserver-test.jar
os.arch=i386
sun.arch.data.model=32
$HOME = /home/esutton
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/i386:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/fesdiagnostics
Dbg: Loading native lib dependencies...
Dbg: System.loadLibrary("fesdiagnostics");
Dbg: loaded fesdiagnostics
Dbg: The undefined symbol _ZN17DiagnosticsServerC1Ev is in libfesdiagnosticsserver.so
Dbg: System.loadLibrary("fesdiagnosticsserver"); 
Dbg: loaded fesdiagnosticsserver
Dbg: System.loadLibrary("jnidiagnosticsserver");
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/fesdiagnostics/libjnidiagnosticsserver.so: /usr/lib/fesdiagnostics/libjnidiagnosticsserver.so: undefined symbol: _ZN17DiagnosticsServerC1Ev
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1732)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
        at fes.JniDiagnostics.libLoad(JniDiagnostics.java:30)
        at fes.JniDiagnostics.<clinit>(JniDiagnostics.java:38)
        at fes.FesDiagnostics.<clinit>(FesDiagnostics.java:17)
        at javadiagnosticsservertest.Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

The environment is the same in both cases:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH =/usr/lib/fesdiagnostics
PATH = /opt/ActivePython-2.7/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin: \
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin: \
/sbin:/opt/qtsdk-2010.01/qt/bin:/home/esutton/bin:/sbin: \
/opt/qtsdk-2010.01/qt/bin
JAVA_HOME = /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26
```

Native C++ Shared Lib Compile Options:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/qtsdk-2010.01/qt/lib -shared \
-Wl,-soname,libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1 \
-o libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0.0 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/ \ 
jnifesdiagnostics.o -L/opt/qtsdk-2010.01/qt/lib -lQtGui \
-L/opt/qtsdk-2010.01/qt/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtCore -lpthread
ln -s libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0.0 libjnidiagnosticsserver.so
ln -s libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0.0 libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1
ln -s libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0.0 libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0
rm -f dist/libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0.0
rm -f dist/libjnidiagnosticsserver.so
rm -f dist/libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1
rm -f dist/libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0
mv -f libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0.0 libjnidiagnosticsserver.so \
\libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1 libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0 dist/
```

When it works under Java 1.4 I must load the dependencies of jnidiagnosticsserver first.  I do not understand why.  I expected that LD_LIBRARY_PATH would have taken care of this:

```
public class JniDiagnostics {

    public native void open(String configurationFile);

    public native void close();

    public native String query(String restfulQueryString);
    private static String[] libraryDependencyList = {"fesdiagnostics", "fesdiagnosticsserver", "jnidiagnosticsserver"};

    private static void libLoad(String libName) {
        System.out.println("Dbg: System.loadLibrary(\"" + libName + "\");");
        System.loadLibrary(libName);
        System.out.println("Dbg: loaded " + libName);
    }

    static //static initializer code
    {
        System.out.println("Dbg: Loading native lib dependencies...");
        for (int i = 0; i < libraryDependencyList.length; i++) {
            libLoad(libraryDependencyList[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

Security issue? Java version configuration issue?

Thanks in advance for any direction,

-Ed

```
CentOS 5.2 32-bit
Netbeans 6.9.1
Java version 1.6.0_26
```

> PS: My goal is to get my Java source to run in a Glassfish RESTful web
>   service.  If LD_LIBRARY_PATH can be solved for a java app, I am hoping the same
>   solution will apply under Glassfish 3.

Comment: You could try to start the VM `java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/fesdiagnostics ...`

Comment: Thanks stacker for the quick reply. Adding java.library.path seems to have no affect: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/fesdiagnostics -jar "javadiagnosticsserver-test.jar"

Comment: @Ed.:Are you compiling the C++ library with any options?

Comment: The shared C++ lib runs fine under Java version 1.4.  Are there C++ options that could affect Java version 1.6 but not 1.4?

Comment: @Ed.:Could be.Why don't you update the OP with how you build the C++ library as well?

Comment: I pasted the native C++ library compile options to the question above.

Comment: I also appended linker commands to C++ commands to OP.

Comment: You are using different `.so` files right? It looks like the definition for the symbol in question (the constructor `DiagnosticsServer::DiagnosticsServer()`) somehow didn't make it to the `.so`. Could you check the C++ compiler output for any error messages related to the file where it should be defined?

Comment: Problem solved.  libjnidiagnosticsserver.so was missing linker lib and path to libfesdiagnosticsserver.so.  Java 1.4 must be more liberal on locating undefined symbols than Java 1.6.  Thank you all for your help. Any suggestions on etiquette for closing this equitably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is a missig dependency of your shared library. Try running the following command to figure this out:

```
ldd -d -r /home/esutton/jnidiagnosticsserver/dist/libjnidiagnosticsserver.so.1.0.0
```

This shows missing symbols.

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` is documented as:

```
Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate 
native-language definition of a method declared native.
```

Comment: Thanks but it runs fine under Java version 1.4 but not under Java version 1.6 so there is no missing dependency.

Comment: Running ldd ./libjnidiagnosticsserver.so and running ldd /usr/lib/fesdiagnostics/libfesdiagnostics.so results in zero "not found" messages.

Comment: Please add the -d switch for more details.

Comment: Are there any spaces in LD_LIBRARY_PATh after the colons ?

Comment: No spaces. I tried ldd -d seems to change the displayed addresses but I see no missing symbols or "not found" messages.  How can it be a dependency issue if it runs under Java version 1.4 ?

Comment: The output shows a different LD_LIBRARY_PATH when run on Java 1.6.

Comment: Yes, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is different on Java 1.6.  Java 1.6 apparently pre-pends a bunch of JDK stuff.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is an UnsatisfiedLinkError. I agree there are missing symbols as ldd -d -r confirms.  The symbols are in a dependent shared lib.  Java 1.4 finds them with no problem, Java 1.6 does not.  Anyway, I am replacing calls to System.load("\absolute\path\to\libmyshared.so") with calls to System.loadLibrary("myshared").  Not sure if I am getting anywhere as while it runs under Java 1.4 it still does not run under Java 1.6.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8036/discussion-between-ed-and-phlogratos)